# linq OrderByDescending returns same result as OrderBy?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, pagedlist

I'm doing something wrong - please show me where!

```
            IPagedList<WebOrderViewModel> viewmodel = null;
            if (Direction == "F")
            {
                viewmodel = db.WebOrders.OrderBy(c => c.CreatedDate)
                    .Join(db.Codes, w => w.OrderStateId, c => c.Id, (w, c) =>
                        new WebOrderViewModel {Order = w, OrderStatus = c.Description})
                    .ToList()
                    .ToPagedList(page, 18);
            }
            else
            {
                viewmodel = db.WebOrders.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDate)
                    .Join(db.Codes, w => w.OrderStateId, c => c.Id, (w, c) =>
                        new WebOrderViewModel { Order = w, OrderStatus = c.Description })
                    .ToList()
                    .ToPagedList(page, 18);  
            }
            ViewBag.Direction = Direction;
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_WebOrdersList", viewmodel);
            }
```

In the above code, I get the exact same result set, even though I have 35 pages of results. The order is always the results of OrderBy regardless of what 'direction' is ("F" [forward] or "R" [reverse]).

I've debugged and that proved to myself that the results were the same when the code goes through each logic path.

I never get the list in reverse order. why?

Comment: What does `ToPagedList` do? And what happens when you move the order by after the join? `.OrderBy(j => j.Order.CreatedDate)` ?

Comment: PagedList just gets the first 'n' records from the query it's attached to. You're saying the join changes the order of the  orderbydescending? This is a multiple precedence sorta thing?

Comment: What is the type of `CreatedDate`?

Comment: CreatedDate is DateTime?

Comment: Does line: `viewmodel = db.WebOrders.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDate)` returns bad data, or it happens in next lines?

Comment: @Rob thank you for your questions! Perfect - it works great now! Put your 'questions' into an answer and I'l mark it as such